# Residue map of a place

Tags: algebraic-curves, function-fields

The following definition for a residue map is given in "Algebraic Curves over a Finite Field" by Hirschfeld, Korchmáros and Torres ([page 265](http://books.google.co.il/books/p/princeton?id=_HJX2SLN-dYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ViewAPI&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

"Let $\Sigma$ be a field of transcendence degree 1 over $K$. For every place $P$ of $\Sigma$, put
$$res_P(x) = \begin{cases} a& \text{if } ord_p(x-a)\ge 0 \\ \infty & \text{if } ord_p(x)<0 \end{cases}$$ 
Then the residue map, $x \to res_p$, associated to $p$ is a $K$-morphism of $\Sigma \cup {\infty}$ onto $K \cup {\infty}$."

They go on and use properties of this map, for example linearity. But some things aren't so clear to me with this definition.

How is it well-defined? If $v_p(x-a) \ge 0$ for some $a \in K$, doesn't it follow that $v_p(x-b) \ge 0$ for any $b \in K$ because of the non-archimedian valuation? Shouldn't the $\ge$ be changed to a strict inequality, i.e. $>$?

If we change it to strict inequality, why is guaranteed that such $a$ exists? I agree that such $a$ exists, but not in $K$ - maybe in a larger set.

So, is there a mistake in the book or am I missing something (or maybe both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition you quote seems to me completely nonsensical.

For example if you take $\Sigma=K(z)$ and for P the valuation at $0$, that is the one with valuation ring $K[z]_{(z)}$, then by everybody's definitiont the rational function $\frac {c}{z} \; (c\in K)$ , or better the differential form  $\frac {c}{z}dz$, should have residue $c$ whereas the authors would have us believe that it is $\infty$.

Why not read the Master Himself, whose relevant [pages 14 and following](http://books.google.fr/books?id=itE4iFpX9OQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=serre+algebraic+groups+and+class+fields&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=kxZuT4y8KsGf0QXBvvWNAg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=serre%20algebraic%20groups%20and%20class%20fields&f=false) Google lets you read for free ?

Comment: He did write about everything! Thanks for the answer, but now I'm stuck - the authors used that definition to show that if $\sigma \in Aut(F/K)$ fixes a place $P$, and $x\in F^{\times}$ and $\sigma(x)$ don't have a pole at $P$, then $v_P(x-\sigma(x)) > 0$. How do I prove it "correctly"?

Comment: I don't know the context, but the way I see it is that $x$ and $\sigma(x)$ are defined at $P$, and have the same value because $\sigma$ fixes $K$, so that $x-\sigma (x)$ vanishes at $P$ i.e. $v_P(x-\sigma(x))\gt 0$.